# Socket conflict while running VAEs

Tags: sockets, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am currently trying to run VAEs on my personal labtop following the steps from: https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE

I am only trying to run the simplest VAE with configs/vae.yaml

Since my personal device only have one gpu so I changed the gpus parameter in the config to [0] and I also add:

```
import os
os.environ["PL_TORCH_DISTRIBUTED_BACKEND"] = "gloo"
```

to run.py to let the file runnable. However, I am now getting such error:

```
Global seed set to 1265
break point 3!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
GPU available: True, used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
break point 4!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
======= Training VanillaVAE =======
Global seed set to 1265
initializing distributed: GLOBAL_RANK: 0, MEMBER: 1/1
[W ..\torch\csrc\distributed\c10d\socket.cpp:558] [c10d] The client socket has failed to connect to [DESKTOP-NMQ53KV]:50425 (system error: 10049 - The requested address is not valid in its context.).
[W ..\torch\csrc\distributed\c10d\socket.cpp:558] [c10d] The client socket has failed to connect to [DESKTOP-NMQ53KV]:50425 (system error: 10049 - The requested address is not valid in its context.).
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
distributed_backend=gloo
All distributed processes registered. Starting with 1 processes
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\core\datamodule.py:469: LightningDeprecationWarning: DataModule.setup has already been called, so it will not be called again. In v1.6 this behavior will change to always call DataModule.setup.
  rank_zero_deprecation(
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

  | Name  | Type       | Params
-------------------------------------
0 | model | VanillaVAE | 3.9 M
-------------------------------------
3.9 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
3.9 M     Total params
15.751    Total estimated model params size (MB)
Validation sanity check:   0%|                                                                   | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]break point 1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
break point 2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Global seed set to 1265
break point 3!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
GPU available: True, used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
break point 4!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
======= Training VanillaVAE =======
Global seed set to 1265
initializing distributed: GLOBAL_RANK: 0, MEMBER: 1/1
[W ..\torch\csrc\distributed\c10d\socket.cpp:401] [c10d] The server socket has failed to bind to [DESKTOP-NMQ53KV]:50425 (system error: 10048 - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.).
[W ..\torch\csrc\distributed\c10d\socket.cpp:401] [c10d] The server socket has failed to bind to DESKTOP-NMQ53KV:50425 (system error: 10013 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.).
[E ..\torch\csrc\distributed\c10d\socket.cpp:435] [c10d] The server socket has failed to listen on any local network address.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\huklab\Desktop\odin\PyTorch-VAE\run.py", line 67, in <module>
    runner.fit(experiment, datamodule=data)
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 737, in fit
    self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 682, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 772, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1132, in _run
    self.accelerator.setup_environment()
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\accelerators\gpu.py", line 39, in setup_environment
    super().setup_environment()
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\accelerators\accelerator.py", line 83, in setup_environment
    self.training_type_plugin.setup_environment()
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\plugins\training_type\ddp.py", line 185, in setup_environment
    self.setup_distributed()
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\plugins\training_type\ddp.py", line 272, in setup_distributed
    init_dist_connection(self.cluster_environment, self.torch_distributed_backend)
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\utilities\distributed.py", line 386, in init_dist_connection
    torch.distributed.init_process_group(
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\distributed\distributed_c10d.py", line 595, in init_process_group
    store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous_iterator)
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\distributed\rendezvous.py", line 257, in _env_rendezvous_handler
    store = _create_c10d_store(master_addr, master_port, rank, world_size, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\huklab\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\distributed\rendezvous.py", line 188, in _create_c10d_store
    return TCPStore(
RuntimeError: The server socket has failed to listen on any local network address. The server socket has failed to bind to [DESKTOP-NMQ53KV]:50425 (system error: 10048 - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.). The server socket has failed to bind to DESKTOP-NMQ53KV:50425 (system error: 10013 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.).
```

Does anyone has any idea what happens and how to fix this?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Which PyTorch Lightning version are you using? I remember it was a problem in old one where there was a bug even when running on a single GPU, it tried to init the process group. Make sure you run a recent version, but you may have to update the code in a few places.